# how can i desactivate the scroll x-y for the main page app.js in react?

Tags: reactjs, scroll

Hello everybody i'm asking how  can i desactivate the scroll x-y  for the main page app.js in react ? 
for example in my class exactly in the app.js i'm returning those lines

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div className="scroll">
        <Ranger />
        <StoryMap data={this.state.data} />

        <div className="App"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

i dont have a index.html so i can desactivate the scroll as i want like 
overflow-y:hidden or overflow : hidden so i create a css class like this

```
.scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and call it 
it doesnt work it only desactivate de x scroll 
Thanks to anyone who takes time to review and give feedback.

Comment: Why dont you try something like :
html {
overflow : hidden
}